# Trouble with buttons (Arduino)

Tags: arduino

StackOverflow! I am a teenager fairly new to Arduino coding, and am investigating a problem. I am running Linux Ubuntu 10.10 if that makes a difference. I have a setup going with a homemade board consisting of five buttons, one for each left, right, up, and down, and one center button, and a Hitachi 2x16 character LCD screen, using the Arduino Uno board.. My programs purpose is to play my splash screen, issue a countdown from three on-screen, display a helpful message, and then go into the program, which simply opens up a list of items, showing one at a time, and allows you to scroll through them using the up and down buttons, and exit the program by clicking the center button. So, here's the problem: the rest of the program works just fine, but when it comes to the menu, it correctly displays the first item, but the buttons do not serve their purpose. I checked using the serial monitor, and the state of the button doesn't change when pressed. But here's the kicker. I used a volt meter to check if the buttons were correctly using power, and they are. They just don't seem to be working digitally. I have checked my wiring, and it is all correct. I think the problem may be in the code, so I leave it to your more experienced hands:

```
// include the library code:
#include <LiquidCrystal.h>

int itemNum = 0;

// Declare variables for on and off states, for efficiency!
int on = LOW;
int off = HIGH;

// Declare the buttons' digital pins and states respectively
const int upbtnpin = 8;
const int dwnbtnpin = 9;
const int cntrbtnpin = 10;

int upbtnstate = off;
int dwnbtnstate = off;
int cntrbtnstate = off;

// initialize the library with the numbers of the interface pins
LiquidCrystal lcd(12, 11, 5, 4, 3, 2);

void setup() {

  // Activate Serial Monitor
  Serial.begin(9600);

  // Declare buttons to be INPUT
  pinMode(upbtnpin, INPUT);
  pinMode(dwnbtnpin, INPUT);  
  pinMode(cntrbtnpin, INPUT);

  // Activate Pullups
  digitalWrite(upbtnpin, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(dwnbtnpin, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(cntrbtnpin, HIGH);

  // Begin LCD
  lcd.begin(16, 2);


  // Splash Screen
  lcd.setCursor(0, 0);
  lcd.print(" _@ Paradigm @_");
  lcd.setCursor(0,1);
  lcd.print("<-> Robotics <->");
  delay(3000);
  lcd.clear();

  // Display Message and countdown
  cntrbtnstate = digitalRead(cntrbtnpin);
  lcd.setCursor(0, 0);
  lcd.print("Menu Program 1.0");
  lcd.setCursor(0, 1);

  int i = 3;
  while (i > 0) {

  if (i == 3) {
    lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
    lcd.print("Wait 3 second(s)");
    delay(1000);
    i--;
  }

  else if (i == 2) {
    lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
    lcd.print("Wait 2 second(s)");
    delay(1000);
    i--;
  }

  else if (i == 1) {
    lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
    lcd.print("Wait 1 second(s)");
    delay(1000);
    i--;
  }

 }
   lcd.clear();
   delay(500);
   lcd.setCursor(0, 0);
   lcd.print("Press enter any");
   lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
   lcd.print(" time to exit. ");
   delay(1200);
   lcd.clear();


}



// ...And finally, to the actual program!

void loop() {
  upbtnstate = digitalRead(upbtnpin);
  dwnbtnstate = digitalRead(dwnbtnpin);
  cntrbtnstate = digitalRead(cntrbtnpin);

  while (cntrbtnstate != on) {

    if (upbtnstate == on) {
      delay(250);
      itemNum++;
    }

    else if (dwnbtnstate == on) {
      delay(250);
      itemNum--;
    }

    // OPTIONAL for debugging
    delay(150);
    Serial.print(" ! "); 
    delay(150);
    Serial.print(int(upbtnstate));
    Serial.print(" ");
    delay(150);
    Serial.print(int(dwnbtnstate));
    Serial.print(" ");
    delay(150);
    Serial.print(int(cntrbtnstate));

    String item = "";
    int itemNum = 0;

    switch(itemNum) {

      case 0:
        lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
        lcd.print("END OF LIST");
        break;
      case 1:
        lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
        lcd.print("Water Bottle");
        break;
      case 2:
        lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
        lcd.print("Biker Jacket");
        break;
      case 3:
        lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
        lcd.print(".44 Magnum");
        break;
      case 4:
        lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
        lcd.print(".44 Rounds (x14)");
        break;
      case 5:
        lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
        lcd.print("Machete");
        break;
      case 6:
        lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
        lcd.print("END OF LIST");
        break;
      default:
        lcd.setCursor(0, 0);
        lcd.print("  An error has  ");
        lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
        lcd.print("    occoured    ");
    }

    if (itemNum > 6) {
      itemNum == 6;
    }

    else if (itemNum < 0) {
      itemNum == 0;
    }

   lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
   lcd.print(item);
  }
  lcd.clear();
  lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
  lcd.print("    Goodbye!    ");

}
```

Comment: Try a simple sketch which does nothing but print the state of the digital inputs to the serial output over and over.  Also, use your voltmeter to verify that the level of the atmega pins corresponding to the buttons changes when you push them.

Comment: @Chris, I have tried both of these things previously, although I thank you for the suggestion. Sorry I did not make that clear.       [EDIT]: I forgot to say that both tests gave perfect results.

Comment: If that works, then make a copy of your current project and start commenting out complexity until you are left with little enough for it to work; then start re-activating things until it breaks again.

Comment: By doing that, I have found out one of the logical errors. In the switch statement, all of the lcd.print(); statements had to be changed to item == "(whatever item was supposed to be)";. However, this has introduced a new problem, after the splash screen and all of that stuff, the LCD doesn't display anything at all! What could be wrong?

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to de-bounce the buttons.

http://arduino.cc/it/Tutorial/Debounce

Second, immediately before your case statement, you set the itemNum to 0. That should probably be moved to the setup section, otherwise it will reset the itemNum each iteration of the loop, and you will always be stuck on "END OF LIST".

Likewise with String item = ""; You are blanking out the string each iteration of the loop, and it runs faster than you can press the buttons.

Also, I don't see any code that ever sets the String item to anything except "". Since you print the item name in the case statement, perhaps you can just remove "String item" and all references.

Finally, you can shorten the delay loop section to :

```
int i = 3;
  while (i > 0) {
    lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
    lcd.print("Wait " + i + " second(s)");
    delay(1000);
    i--;
  }
```

Comment: I will try debouncing. As far as the other things go, I have just recently before reading this fixed them, ironically. And for the shortened delay loop, I had that originally set when I made the first version of the program, but it gave, and still gives (I just checked) the error 'invalid operands of types ‘const char*’ and ‘const char [11]’ to binary ‘operator+’' Thank you for the other suggestions, though :)

Comment: Try    `lcd.print(sprintf("Wait %d second(s)", i));`